# Impala JDBC connection doesn't close properly in Java MultithreadCode

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, impala

I have some java multithread code that do a calculation reading from Impala with JDBC a lot of times.
My problem is that in my cluster, that counts 6 nodes, the connectin aren't closed by the code, althought I had insert the close() statement. In this way the 64*6 simultaneous connection are used, and the cluster stop accepting new request, and my software stop working.
I tried increase the 64 connections limit by adding:
--be_service_threads=256
--fe_service_threads=256
to impalad start script, and nothing changed but the duration of execution, that is 4 times longer as expectable.
To complete the description, my code sends request splitted in equal part to every 6 impalad. For every set of request it creates a thread, that open a new connection, do the calculations, then close resultset, statement and connection. The thread live for the application duration, and can't be killed for how is structured the code.
Here an example that reproduces the error:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Starting");
    try{
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:impala://<myimpalaserver>:21050/;auth=noSasl;";
    String jdbcDriverName = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver";

    Class.forName(jdbcDriverName);
    logger.info("Tentativo di connessione a " + connectionUrl);
    int count = 0;
    try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    logger.info("Executing query");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select 2");
    logger.info("Query terminata");
    while (rs.next()) {
       ++count;
    }
    } finally {
    if (rs != null) try {
    logger.info("#output rows: " + count + ". Closing resultset");
    rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore){}
    if (stmt != null) try {
    logger.info("closing statemenet");
    stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore){}
    if (con != null) try {
    logger.info("closing connection");
    logger.info("Connection Status:"+con.isClosed());
    con.close();
    logger.info("Connection Status:"+con.isClosed());
    } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore){}
    }
    logger.info("sleeping");
    Thread.sleep(1000000);
    System.out.println("Finishing");
    }

    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

I think is some problem with hiveserver2 connection that impala made, but I'm not sure. The Java code should be correctly wrapped as best practide said.
Has anyone encounter this issue or similar issues before? How did you resolve it?

Comment: this is terrible code for dozens of reasons ...

Comment: The code was just for example, and is taken from the cloudera JDBC guide. I add the suggestion read on the other post and nothing changed. Post edited.